# IPv4フラグメンテーション結合時にIPヘッダー項目で結合対象とする項目

Tags: network

IPフラグメンテーションパケットを結合する際に、IPヘッダーで使用する項目は以下のフィールドのみでしょうか？
 - Identification (ID)
 - Source IP Address
 - Destination IP Address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC791 Internet Protocol Specification Fragmentation and Reassembly](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791#section-3.2) の項目より
結合対象とするパケットは IPv4パケットでかつ、DFフラグが立っておらず、MFフラグが立っているまたはOffsetが0でないパケットで、以下の項目が一致するものです。Protocolも対象です。

- Identification (ID)
- Source IP Address
- Destination IP Address
- Protocol

なお、[RFC6864 Updated Specification of the IPv4 ID Field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6864) によってIDフィールドはフラグメンテーションにのみ使用すると用途が限定されています。

そのほか参考にした資料:
[Wikipedia IPv4 Reassembly(英語)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Reassembly)
[linux/net/ipv4/ip_fragment.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/ip_fragment.c#L121)